# Is my contractor guy doing a botch up job with repointing

Tags: concrete, brick, masonry

Is my contractor guy doing a botch up job with repointing.
Is it normal that it's drying out all cracked up like this and it's easy to crumble.
They are only using the masonry cement type S and color are they supposed to be mixing it with sand to strengthen? Is this just the first layer? So was able to add screen shots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That picture would be really important; if you can't get it edited in, post the URL and someone will be along to edit the image in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is terrible and unacceptable.

The mortar has been mixed with too much water causing it to dry (cure) and crack. When mixed, it should be the consistency of thick paste. There should be no water oozing out when mixed and sitting on the board before “placed”.

Cracking will allow moisture infiltration. It’s useless. Remove it and re-do. Do not just reapply another drier coat over the cracks. (Type S is acceptable for above grade use.)

Comment: I agree this cracked mess needs to be removed and done correctly.